# How Next button works in Vuestic Admin

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue Js, I am using form wizard from http://vuestic.epicmax.co/#/forms/form-wizard, I am not sure from the below code how next button works in this wizard form. For a single step in wizard, **onNext** function has below code,

```
{
    label: this.$t('forms.wizard.stepOne'),
    slot: 'page1',
    onNext: () => {
        this.validateFormField('hsName')
    },
    isValid: () => {
        return this.isFormFieldValid('hsName')
    }
}
```

but, **validateFormField** has nothing related to moving to the next step,

```
methods: {
    isFormFieldValid (field) {
        let isValid = false
        if (this.formFields[field]) {
            isValid = this.formFields[field].validated && this.formFields[field].valid
        }
        return isValid
    },
    validateFormField (fieldName) {
        this.$validator.validate(fieldName, this[fieldName])
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also I want to remove the *next* button instead put multiple select buttons on the form, clicking on any one of them will move to next step...

Comment: The wizard is a package that comes with the vuestic-admin theme. You just can't remove it unless you want to edit the core js files. Also, `next` expects `return true` or `return false` so that it will proceed/fail simultaneously